# ListView Will not re-rendered on state change

Tags: javascript, listview, react-native

Problem is this. Based on a state variable, i either render a reusable component on a ListView renderRow, or i return null.

```
//renderRow 
if (this.state.openSections[sectionID] === false) {return null}

    return (<View style = {{flex :1, overflow : 'hidden'}}>
                <CalculatorItem item = {rowData}></CalculatorItem>
             </View>)
```

When a section is pressed, the corresponding entry in openSections objects toggles to true or false, indicating that the rows should render, in order to be visible to the user.

```
sectionPressed: function(sectionID) {
    ...
        //create a new openSections var and set the state
        this.setState((state, props) => { return {  openSections }});
    }
```

However, the listview Items, are not rendered.

Any clues?

Comment: Need more context. Where's the list view?

Comment: Could you share the code here?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the ListView gets re-rendered only when its data source gets changed. Otherwise, it stays as is. So, when you change your state, you might want to change the value in the dataSource property as well.